problema al abrir una ventana en el .exe Python
Tengo un archivo principal desde donde ejecuto la apertura de una nueva ventana cuyo codigo se encuentra en otro archivo asi como sigue:
class mywindow(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    super(mywindow, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.parent = parent
    #self.icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("WhatsApp-Bulk-and-Customized-Messages-Without-Saving-Contacts-main\whatsapp_socialnetwork_17360.ico"))
    self.pack()  
    root.title('Nutricion Celular')  
    #self.master.iconphoto(True, self.icon)
    self.Create_widget()
    self.create_menu_window()

def abrir_ventana1(self):
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "Interface2.py"])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    mywindow(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()

El codigo del otro archivo seria el siguiente:
class mywindow2(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    super(mywindow2, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
    #self.icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("WhatsApp-Bulk-and-Customized-Messages-Without-Saving-Contacts-main\whatsapp_socialnetwork_17360.ico"))
    root.title('Creacion de Menu')
              
    #self.master.iconphoto(True, self.icon)        
    self.Create_widget()
if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()
mywindow2(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()

Cuando lo ejecuto a traves de VSCode no tiene ningun problema, pero cuando realizo el .exe usando pyinstaller el programa se ejecuta pero no abre la ventana al momento de hacer click en el boton de abrir la nueva ventana, podria alguien ayudarme? Gracias

Hola Jose, ¿hay alguna razón de peso por la que usas un subproceso para crear otra ventana en vez de hacerlo todo en el mismo hilo con tkinter.Toplevel?

Hola, no como tal, empece a usar subprocesos porque lo que debia desarrollar en la ventana nueva era muy extenso y debia realizar  varios calculos y presentarlos al usuario, recien estoy retomando el desarrollo de apps por lo que no tengo mucha experiencia en el tema

Hay dos problemas con el enfoque que estás usando, ambos localizados en:
subprocess.Popen(["python", "Interface2.py"])

El primer problema es que si usas --onefile tienes que resolver la ruta a Interface2.py de forma adecuada, en este caso es un recurso más y no un módulo que importas.
El segundo problema es el que tiene peor solución, estás intentando ejecutar al propio intérprete Python en un subproceso mediante subprocess.Popen. Eso en si mismo no está mal, el problema es que lo haces desde un ejecutable de PyInstaller.
El proceso por el que PyInstaller genera un ejecutable se conoce como freezing ("congelado"). En esencia consiste en recopilar el código fuente de la app, todas sus dependencias, los recursos de la misma y el propio intérprete Python y empaquetarlo todo en un mismo fichero o archivo comprimido. El objetivo es poder ejecutar la app en un sistema que no tenga el intérprete Python ni las dependencias de la app instalados.
Cuando usas Popen desde el exe la idea no es llamar al intérprete instalado en el sistema operativo, porque entonces usar PyInstaller no tiene sentido, la idea sería ejecutar el intérprete embebido en el propio ejecutable. Ésto, al menos que yo sepa, no es posible de forma simple.
En vez de complicarte la vida con este enfoque, te aconsejo simplemente usar tkinter.Toplevel para generar las ventanas que quieras en tu app, todas en el mismo hilo principal. Si parte de tu código necesita ejecutarse de forma asíncrona puedes usar threading (I/O bound) o multiprocess (CPU bound), simplemente recuerda:

Solo debes ejecutar y modificar la interfaz y cualquier Widget de Tkinter desde el hilo principal. Tkinter (y la mayoría de framework gráficos) no es thread-safe. Simplemente procesa lo que sea en el hilo/proceso y luego comunica de forma segura los resultados (o el progreso) al hilo principal para que actualice la interfaz.

Solo debe haber una instancia de tkinter.Tk, pero puedes crear cuantas ventanas secundarias quieras con tkinter.Toplevel, ocultándolas, mostrándolas o destruyéndolas según te convenga.


Por ejemplo:
import tkinter as tk
from interface2 import MyWindow2


class MyWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Abrir ventana",
            command=self.abrir_ventana
        ).pack()

    def abrir_ventana(self):
        toplevel = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        MyWindow2(toplevel).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        toplevel.title('Creacion de Menu')
        toplevel.geometry('600x150')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MyWindow(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.title('Ventana principal')
    root.geometry('600x150')
    root.mainloop()

e interface2.py:
import tkinter as tk

class MyWindow2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        ...

Tu ventana principal (instancia de tkinter.Tk) no debes destruirla durante toda la ejecución, pero si necesitas ocultarla simplemente usa su método withdraw, junto adeiconify para mostrarla de nuevo.

Excelente muchas gracias por la ayuda ya lo aplique y trabaja bien!!
